# Can I change the width of the Solution Configuration combobox in the IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Can I increase the width of the Solution Configuration combobox of MS Visual Studio IDE? I want to see the full name, for example `Debug (Local)` or `Debug (Remote)`. Also tooltip writes the `Solution Configuration` text instead of combobox' current value.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes you can. you must enter in "add or remove buttons -> customize". Inside the commands tab select the button you want to customize and click "modify selection" you change the width value there. Take a look here

http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/08/14/adjusting-the-width-of-solution-configurations-drop-down-list-in-the-visual-studio-toolbar/

Comment: Inside the "Commands" tab, select radio "Toolbar", then at combobox select "Standard"

Comment: Thanks to the OP for asking this and the reply contributions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was bothering me for years... I don't understand while they did not make that DropDownList size automatically adapt to content (with a max of  200px?)

Answer (score 52):

Same same but different in VS 2019:

1. Go to 'Tools --> Customize'.
2. In the 'Commands' tab, select 'Toolbar: Standard'.
3. Select 'Solution Configurations' and click 'Modify Selection'. You can adjust the width there.

[image]

Comment: Works for VS 2022 as well